# Store image as binary data in SQL Server and display in img tag using Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, file-upload

I have a column `user_pic(varbinary(max))` in my SQL Server database. Using Laravel, I can store uploaded picture in this column like:

```
 $path = $request->file('image')->getRealPath();
 $img = file_get_contents($path);
 $string = unpack("H*hex",$img);
 $string = '0X'.$string['hex'];
 $data->user_pic = DB::raw("CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), $string)");
```

But I can not find a way to display this image in HTML IMG tag. I did the following but its not working:

```
@php    
$string = base64_encode(pack('H*', sprintf('%u', CRC32($user->user_pic) ) ) );
echo '<img src="data:image/PNG;base64,'.$string.'" />';
@endphp
```

When I inspect IMG tag I can see this as src attribute value

```
<img src="data:image/PNG;base64,EQAxaEE=" />
```

Comment: Some browsers may treat MIME types in a case-sensitive manner. Have you tried `image/png` instead of `image/PNG`? Also that base64 string looks incorrect. Base64 encoded PNG files typically start with `iVBOR...`

Comment: If the `user_pic` value in the table doesn't start with `0x89504E470D0A...` then it's probably not being saved correctly from Laravel.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for your time, I checked `user_pic` value in table is starting with `0xFFD8FFE000104...`

Comment: FYI that looks like a JFIF based .jpg file, not a .png file. It should be outputting to the browser something similar to `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RiDR...` once you've got everything correct.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning again thanks for suggestion. I changed this line
`$string = base64_encode(pack('H*', sprintf('%u', CRC32($user->user_pic) ) ) );` to this one
`$string = base64_encode($user->user_pic);` hurrah!.. it worked but one thing I couldnt understand.. Image is displayed in both way of data attribute:
`data:image/jpeg and data:image/PNG` means mime type is not important. I think so. any idea on this?